# Find array of objects from keys array

Tags: javascript, typescript, underscore.js, lodash

I have an array of object

```
let objList = [
 {
  id:10,
  ...
 },

 {
  id: 12,
  ...
 },

 {
  id: 13,
  ...
 },

 ...
];
```

and I wanted to filter out all the objects whose IDs are in another array

```
let keyList = [10, 13];

Expected output:

[
 {
  id: 10,
  ...
  },

 {
  id: 13,
  ...
 }
]
```

**Note**:

> The req.  is in an Angular 7 application and I use Lodash library as well.

I tried:

```
objList.filter(eachObj => keysList.forEach(
          eachID => {
            eachID == eachObj['id']
          }
        ))
```

and

```
find(ObjList, eachObj => {

          return eachObj['id'] === keysList.map(eachID => {
            return eachID;
          })
        })
```

Comment: `let result = objList.filter(({id}) => keyList.includes(id))`

Comment: Question displays no effort to solve the problem. Always show us what you have tried and what you have researched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter:

```
objList = objList.filter(element => keyList.indexOf(element.id) > -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not get the desired result as you did not get `id` field from your array.
So try to use `includes` method and get `id` property:

```
const filteredArray = objList.filter(o => keyList.includes(o.id));
console.log(filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `_.differenceWith()` to compare the `id` with the `key`, and remove items that exist in both arrays:

```js
const objList = [{ id: 10 }, { id: 12 }, { id: 13 }];
const keyList = [10, 13];

const result = _.differenceWith(objList, keyList, ({ id }, key) => id === key);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.13/lodash.js"></script>
```